# Post-mortem debugging C# app with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windbg, postmortem-debugging

I'm struggling to debug a `.dmp` file that contains .NET code (C#), it also contains managed C++ who calls into native code

The `.dmp` file is a "full dump"

If I load the `.pdb` in WinDBG, using SOS, life is good - however if I load into Visual Studio 2010 I'm unable to get CLR stacks? It feels like VS doesn't recognize the app as a managed app

Are there tricks? Should I use windbg instead (I'd really prefer VS)

Does VS2012 perform better?

Answer (score 0):

try this link but i prefer using Windbg with source path
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx